# What types of indirect references are and aren't allusions?

Tags: rhetoric, allusion, poetic-devices

In school I learned that allusions are indirect references.

Often my teachers would give examples in the form of references to well-known literary works.

If I say "I can read the writing on the wall", I'm making a reference to the hand of God writing a prophesy of doom at the feast of Belshazzar in the book of Daniel, and comparing it to my own situation.

Or if I throw you a can of Sprite and say "here, obey your thirst", I'm alluding facetiously to the Sprite commercials from the late 90s.

These are the type of indirect references that I'm sure are allusions. But if the purpose of allusion as a poetic/rhetorical technique is to make the reader feel kinship through referencing the things we all know about, then I'm curious whether other indirect references would qualify as allusions.

A couple examples I'm curious about:

> Isn't it romantic? / Moving shadows write / The oldest magic word

—"Isn't It Romantic" by Rodgers & Hart

"The oldest magic word" is referring indirectly, and via a metaphor, to love. We all know that love is ancient and magical. Would this qualify as an allusion?

> "I know when that hotline bling / That can only mean one thing"

—"Hotline Bling" by Drake

The "one thing" that Drake's phone ringing late at night can mean is that the girl he's talking about is DTF. We understand what he's referring to and he doesn't have to say it directly. Does this qualify as an allusion?

Comment: Short answer? Yes and yes. An allusion is nothing more than an implicit reference to something.

Comment: When *I* say *the writing on the wall* it has nothing at all to do with Belshazzar. Other people may *infer* that, but I'm certainly not *implying* that—nor am I comparing *that* to my own situation. It can still be an allusion, but it's not necessarily the allusion that *you're* thinking it is. This is similar to Blake and the ringing phone.  If  *I* said that, it would mean something quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/art/allusion) gives the following explanation:

> Allusion, in literature, an implied or indirect reference to a person, event, or thing or to a part of another text. Most allusions are based on the assumption that there is a body of knowledge that is shared by the author and the reader and that therefore the reader will understand the author’s referent. The word allusion comes from the late Latin allusio meaning “a play on words” or “game” and is a derivative of the Latin word alludere, meaning “to play around” or “to refer to mockingly.”
>
> In traditional Western literature, allusions to figures in the Bible and from Greek mythology are common. *However,* **some authors**, such as the Modernist writers T.S. Eliot and James Joyce, ***deliberately used obscure and complex allusions in their work that they knew few readers would readily understand***.

[William Irwin in his article published in The Journal of Aesthetics and Art Criticism](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/1540-6245.00026) says

> (...) Allusions, then, to be understood and interpreted
>   correctly must accord with authorial intent.
>
> What about connections between texts that
>   readers make independent of authorial intent?

Such connections are what we called accidental
associations. We do not want to limit the reading
process to recognizing authorial intent, but we
do want to distinguish between readings that accord
with authorial intent and those that do
not. As Hermerén says with regard to his own
definition of allusion, “The definitions outlined
here do not exclude that literary critics take an
interest in what a text suggests to more or less
well-educated readers, regardless of what the
author intended.”5 We, as readers, can generate
much aesthetic value on the basis of our own
readings. The text may suggest many things that
the author did not actually intend, but that an
ideal, or merely reasonable, reader is correct to
notice. There is no harm in taking notice of these
things as long as we do not incorrectly attribute
them to the author or his or her text. They are,
properly speaking, our reading, which in fact
may be a misreading.

Based on Brittanica and Irwin's explanations, I would say that yes, your examples qualify as allusions i.e. the authors intended their readers/listeners to make mental connections with what came before.

More examples, from  [everyday speech and literature here](https://literarydevices.net/allusion/), and [bilical allusions here](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-allusion.html)